# Transform (shear) a draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I use the jquery `draggable` to make this div movable in the window.

[image: The movable div.]

[image: When the div is dragged I want to be deformed.]

When it is dragged (in this chase, to right) I want to be deformed like the image above.

Thank you so much in advance!

If you want more info, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
<script>  
$(function() {
var prevX = -1;

$('.movable').draggable({
drag: function(e) {
    //console.log(e.pageX);
    // dragged left
    if(prevX > e.pageX) {
        $(this).addClass('cls');
    }
    else if(prevX < e.pageX) { // dragged right
        $(this).removeClass('cls').addClass('cls2');
    }
    prevX = e.pageX;
},
stop: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('cls').removeClass('cls2');
}
});

});
</script>
```

If is dragged to right it would be like your photo, and if is dragged to left it would be transformed to 175deg.

**CSS:**

```
.cls {
-webkit-transform:skewX(5deg);
-moz-transform:skewX(5deg);
-ms-transform:skewX(5deg);
-o-transform:skewX(5deg);
}
.cls2 {
-webkit-transform:skewX(175deg);
-moz-transform:skewX(175deg);
-ms-transform:skewX(175deg);    
-o-transform:skewX(175deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BLhf6/)</kbd>

**js**

```
$("#drag").draggable({
    drag: function () {
        $(this).addClass('cls');//add class on dragging 
    },
    stop: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('cls');//remove class on drag stop
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.cls {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div></div>
```

.

```
$("div").draggable({
drag: function () {
    $(this).addClass('skew');
},
stop: function () {
    $(this).removeClass('skew');
}
});
```

.

```
div {
height:300px;
width:150px;
background-color:cornflowerblue;
}

.skew {
transform: skew(-20deg,0);
-moz-transform:skew(-20deg,0);
-webkit-transform:skew(-20deg,0);
-o-transform:skew(-20deg,0);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMU9x/1/)